# how to remember regular expression quantifications?

Tags: regex, quantifiers

I have trouble remembering the quantifications, i.e i know what they all mean but does anyone have an easy way to recall which one stands for which ?

```
?   The question mark indicates there is zero or one of the preceding element.
*   The asterisk indicates there is zero or more of the preceding element.
+   The plus sign indicates there is one or more of the preceding element.
```

I'll give an example of the answer i'm looking for.

> to distinguish between  horizontal and vertical, take the first letter H the line in the middle of the letter 'H' is the direction that the word denotes. the letter 'V' has two lines which go up ,so thats the direction the word means.

Comment: Wend your way through Mastering Regular Expressions.  Practice....daily.

Comment: @DavidO I don't use regular expressions regularly ,just sometimes to find and replace stuff and I tend to mix them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
?    is_whatever? returs boolean (0 or 1)
*    0 * 1 = 0 (0 or more)
+    0 + 1 = 1 (1 or more)
```

Comment: I dont know if you meant the conditional operator "?" in C if so then that's a neat way to remember the operator. thanks

Comment: Yes either `?:` in C# or `a_boolean_function?` in Ruby will remember me this.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is a bend line which stand for 1 and a dot (a circle) which stands for zero.

The asterisk is a larger dot thus zero or more.

The + has a vertical line (representing one) and another one (thus one or more).